# Rspec group test ouput

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

How group some tests to be displayed in a group ?

I launch :

```
bin/rspec --format=documentation
```

Actual, I got :

```
Countries API
  GET /countries
    return list of countries
    returns status code 200
  GET /states/{country_abbrev}
    return list of states
    returns status code 200

Companies API
  GET /companies
    returns companies
    returns status code 200

InvoiceLineRepository
  #create
    create invoice line in database

InvoiceRepository
  #create
    create invoice in database
```

And I want to have :

```
  API  
    Countries API
      GET /countries
        return list of countries
        returns status code 200
      GET /states/{country_abbrev}
        return list of states
        returns status code 200

    Companies API
      GET /companies
        returns companies
        returns status code 200

 Repository  
    InvoiceLineRepository
      #create
        create invoice line in database

    InvoiceRepository
      #create
        create invoice in database
```

The tests that's concern API, are grouped togheter. 
The tests that's concern Repository, are grouped togheter.

I want this to better organize the visualisation and exploration of my tests

**EDIT :**

context (see mrzasa response) do not fill my requirements :

```
Repository
  AddressRepository
    #create
      create address in database

Repository
  AgencyRepository
    #create
      create agency in database

Repository
  ArticleRepository
    #create
      create article in database
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a [custom formatter](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/formatters/custom-formatters), take a look at the [documentation formatter](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/formatters/documentation_formatter.rb) for an example, but as others have said this does not scale, and what exactly is a "group"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add contexts for `API` and `Repository`:

```
context 'API' do
  context 'Countries' do
    describe 'GET /countries' do
      # examples
    end
    describe 'GET /states/{country_abbrev}' do
      # examples
    end
  end
end

context 'Repository do
   # context/describe blocks for  InvoiceLineRepository and  InvoiceRepository
end
```

Comment: I updated my answer, context do not fill my requirements =/

Comment: ...But it's worth pointing out that this idea does not scale. It may look pretty for tiny output like OP's, but if you have 100s of endpoints then this file will quickly grow out of control and become difficult to maintain.